# Has Bruce Wayne ever dated a woman who did NOT find out he was Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, secret-identity

A common joke I've seen online is that Bruce Wayne can't seem to date a woman without her either A) dying or B) eventually finding out he's Batman. I know of several cases where he entered a semi-serious relationship with a woman, but oddly enough both criteria apply to those (usually the latter one). So this leads me to believe that the joke is based in reality after all.

**Has Bruce Wayne/Batman ever been in a serious relationship with a woman who did NOT die or learn of his dual identity?**

All media acceptable - comics, movies, cartoons, whatever. I assume there won't be too many answers, since I'm looking for actual dating relationships and not just the "arm candy" he occasionally employs for appearances.

Comment: Do Elseworlds/imaginary stories count? I doubt Julie Madison ever discovered his identity in continuity, but there might well have been one or more imaginary stories where she and Bruce got married, and she knew his identity.

Comment: “Bruce Wayne can't seem to date a woman without her either A) dying or B) eventually finding out he's Batman” — or, spoilers for the Nolan Batman movies, both!

Comment: Diana. She found out the reverse that Batman is the Bruce Wayne.

Comment: How do you feel about the following sequence of events? 1) Bruce Wayne and a certain young woman go on more than one date during a certain writer's run on a Batman comic book. 2) She doesn't learn his secret. 3) Then there's a change in writers, and the young woman is not mentioned in the comics for a few years. 4) Then she is brought back onstage just in time to be murdered as a tragic touch to launch a new story arc. So she didn't learn the secret, nor die, *while they were dating,* but she was treated as cannon fodder *much later.* (I think this pattern has happened at least twice!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Characters found via https://www.ranker.com/list/batmans-long-list-of-lovers/charlie-knauf: Candidates of women Batman dated who neither died nor discovered his identity include

- [Julie Madison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julie_Madison) - Julie was engaged to Bruce Wayne, but left him due to him constantly flaking on her due to his role as Batman (the New 52 continuity has her learn Batman's identity in part of a scheme to restore Bruce's memories of being Batman)
- [Lorna Shore](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Lorna_Shore_(New_Earth)) - Lorna and Bruce dated, but he dumped her after an encounter with The Joker made him fear she might one day get caught in the crossfire.
- [Shondra Kinsolving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shondra_Kinsolving) - had a relationship while Bruce was recovering from his broken back courtesy of Bane. While she didn't die, the relationship was ended due to her psychological trauma at the hand of her brother, Benedict Asp.
- [Mallory Moxon](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/mallory-moxon/4005-79486/) - Childhood friends, fell for each other as adults, but the relationship was ended when Mallory's father, a crime lord, was paralyzed, and Mallory took control of the organization.
- [Rachel Caspian](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Rachel_Caspian_(New_Earth)) - Daughter of The Reaper. Relationship ended when she became a nun after finding out her father's criminal identity.
- [Linda Page](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Linda_Page) - Fellow socialite, relationship ended because she couldn't understand Bruce's frequent disappearances to be Batman and because she was convinced he was a shiftless playboy who wouldn't amount to anything.